# D3.js add label to only zoomed to feature

Tags: d3.js, label

I have a D3.js version 4 map of US counties. When a user enters a zipcode in an input textbox, the map zooms to the corresponding county. Now, I want to add a label to the zoomed county.  I haven't been successful. The labels are not showing on top of the county. Instead they're showing BELOW my map.  Here's my label code snippet:

```
var label = svg.select("text")
    .data(conus.features)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "1em")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                    if (svg.select(".county").classed("active") === true) {
                        return "translate(" + path.centroid(conus.features[0]) + ")";
                    }
                })
    .text(function (d) {
        if (svg.select(".county").classed("active") === true) {
                        return conus.features[0].properties.County;
                    }
                });
```

I have class "active" that I assign to the selected/zoomed county. So I only want that class to have the label.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you set up a test version somewhere? The general approach for label is that they should be position as absolute

Comment: @LoredraL This is an SVG, there is no `absolute` position for text elements. The problem here is just the drawing order of the elements, the easiest solution being calling a `raise()` just after appending the text. However, for a proper answer, I suggest you (user2770113) to create a [MCVE].

Comment: @GerardoFurtado : 1 of the approach for tooltip style label is that we attachs an absolute positioned div on mouseover event in d3. But yeah, without more information nothing can be done.

Comment: Hi, everyone who tried to respond. Please check out http://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu

Select one of the field conditions from dropdownlist, (never mind landuse-it's still on development). Then enter a zip code and press tab (pressing enter button doesn't work).  The map zooms to the county where the zipcode is and I want to label the county on the map.  Appreciate your help